# How long and where does data stay in tcp socket

Tags: sockets, kernel, tcp

TCP sender application wants to send data so it writes to socket with write() system-call and then write() returns. Now socket to NIC happens behind the scenes by kernel and nic drivers based on how much data can be sent on wire keeping tcp connection's properties (congestion window and all) in mind.

Now, does this data sit in the socket till a successful notification of receipt (TCP ACK) comes back from the client?

I want to know how long and where data is retained so that it can be sent again in case of tcp packet loss.

Answer (score 1):

TCP is a reliable transport.  It handles retransmissions automatically.  If data loss does occur, the connection is deemed broken/lost, and your code will start receiving error codes on subsequent socket operations until you close the socket.  You don't need to worry about retransmitting data manually with TCP (only with UDP).  Once the data is in the kernel, it handles the rest for you.  And yes, the data sits in the kernel until the peer ACKs it, retransmitting as needed until the socket times out internally.

Comment: Thanks Remy. I confirmed in source code that we keep data in socket buffer till we get ack and only after that we release the acked data. And I do understand tcp semantics of "reliable" delivery. I know kernel will take care of data. I just wanted to understand how. Part I was/am interested in knowing was the async nature of app writing to socket and going away and socket writing to wire. So, for example, if I wanted to know when exactly a particular chunk of data got to receiver, I can't right now from the app perspective. App writes to socket and goes away. Loss may cause retransmissions.

Comment: Again, you don't need to handle retransmissions manually in TCP. Your code should not be trying to track that info to begin with. Once the data is in the kernel, assume it will be sent and move on. The only way to detect low-level TCP acks is to sniff the network adapter directly, such as with a pcap library.  At the application layer, the only way to know if the data has reached the receiver is if the receiver sends back an acknowledgement at the protocol layer, which your app would have to read from the socket and process as needed.